# Crafty.js Tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, game-engine, craftyjs

This question has probably been asked before, but I didn't find it while searching.

Can anybody point me towards a good up to date tutorial for Crafty.js? I cannot seem to find one and I am having trouble getting my head around it. If there are no good tutorials, then are there any alternative HTML5 game engine libraries with a good tutorial?

**Edit:** I have tried reading 'starmelts' tutorials, but they seem a little bit confusing for me.

**Edit 2:** The HTML5 game engine only has to work on desktop browsers, but especially chrome.

Comment: Hey! Any reason for the download on this question? It's closed, so it's not like I've can update it......

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am aware, that this question is quite old, but since it is highly ranked on google and there are so few well known tutorials available I going to post this link anyway.

http://buildnewgames.com/introduction-to-crafty/

This is a really good, quick and  up to date craftyjs tutorial. It teaches the key concepts of using this framework, by developing a small game.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Changing the accepted answer to make sure that the accepted answer it up to date.

Answer (score 10):

I've tested crafty a while back, haven't had a chance to work with it though.

But when I was testing it, I've found these links useful.

http://cykod.github.com/Presentations/HTML5/Crafty/
and starmelt tutorial as you already know 
https://github.com/starmelt/craftyjstut/wiki

Craftyjs doesn't have strong documentation yet, but there are some good articles scattered around that you might find useful. If you really want to, drop me a line, and I'll try and help you understand it as this will also help me.

Comment: Thanks for the links! How can I get in touch if I need help? Should I post a comment here?

Comment: I agree that crafty.js definitely needs more tutorials.

Comment: Good question, I thought it was possible to send messages between users. Apparently it isn't. 
I'm updating my personal profile with contact information, I guess this is the accepted way of SO.

Comment: I wouldn't know what the accepted way is

Comment: Check my profile page. You'll find a way to get in touch if you need.

Comment: Thanks! I may post a comment here instead, but I will see.

Answer (score 4):

The creating your first crafty game tutorial has moved [here](http://craftyjs.github.com/tutorial/bananabomber/create-a-game)

Answer (score 3):

I would start with the [offical tutorial](http://craftyjs.com/tutorials.php). At first glance it looks pretty thorough.

Comment: Thanks! I could not find this tutorial when I looked. I will have a read and if I need more help, I will post again.

Comment: Does the tutorial go any further?

Comment: There are several links to helpful material at the top.

Comment: The 'Creating your first Crafty game' link is broken (apparently the domain does not exist), the 'Building an RPG' link links to an outdated tutorial, and starmelt's tutorial seem too complex for me.